# known and "unknown" incompatibilities between sql 2005 and 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, migration, compatibility

as usual, we'd like to think that there won't be any trouble migrating our applications to the latest sql version...

but...

but...

but...

well, just to be prepared, has anybody stumbled into some nasty incompatibility issue?

(for example, I remeber that after migrating from 2000 to 2005, one linked server we had to a sql 6.5 server stopped working)

Comment: I think incompatibilities, if any, are documented in "What's new" and other places in books online.

Comment: yeah, of course, as with every new release, I was referring to the "undocumented" ones...

Answer (score 1):

The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) list of deprecated features is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article [Backward Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280407.aspx) for SQL Server 2008 covers all of the major components.