# SQL server 2008 features/benefits?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Duplicate of:**

- [known and “unknown” incompatibilities between sql 2005 and 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845271/known-and-unknown-incompatibilities-between-sql-2005-and-2008)
- [SQL Server 2005 vs SQL Server 2008 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725248/sql-server-2005-vs-sql-server-2008-closed)
- [Advantages of MS SQL Server 2008 over MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-ms-sql-server-2008-over-ms-sql-server-2005)

And many more.

---

Hi

I have been using SQL server 2000 for a few years but now have access to SQL server 2008 for development.

Apart from the obvious things like the new management studio and intellisense what are the main features and benefits of SQL server 2008?

What is the general consensus on the performance of the management studio compared to the out dated SQL 2000 enterprise manager and query analyzer applications?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Management Studio from SQL2008 against a SQL2000 Database.

Comment: Well, this is partially true. If you're stuck with a really old version of SQL 2000, you're only allowed to open a query window. The tree view can't check out tables/procedures/etc. I believe if you're running version 8.0 of SQL 2000 or above, you're okay.

Comment: What version was SQL 2000 prior to 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198478/advantages-of-ms-sql-server-2008-over-ms-sql-server-2005). Granted the title is for advantages of 2008 over 2005, I think the feature list is quite comprehensive and will show you all that 2000 isn't offering.

SQL Server Management Studio is a lot nicer than Enterprise Manager. It is a little different since SSMS uses more of a Visual Studio interface. But there are lot more features in SSMS easily available.